# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания и объяснить их?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, двоеточие, знак

Не важно() что это() радио в такси или попавшая в почтовый ящик газета.

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать все возможные варианты, то их будет три:

(1) *Не важно, что это **рАдио** в такси или попавшая в почтовый ящик **газЕта.***

(2) *Не важно, **чтО** это: **рАдио** в такси или попавшая в почтовый ящик **газЕта**.*  (3) *Не важно, **чтО** это — **рАдио** в такси или попавшая в почтовый ящик **газЕта**.*

**Грамматика  разная.**

**Вариант (1):** Сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным, **ЧТО — изъяснительный союз (безударный)**. ЭТО — подлежащее, радио или газета — однородные сказуемые, они выделены ударением.

**Варианты (2) и (3)**: ЭТО — подлежащее, **ЧТО — обобщающее слово** **в ударной позиции,** оно является сказуемым, радио или газета — однородные сказуемые, они также выделены ударением.

Варианты (2) и (3) различаются **интонационно**. При постановке двоеточия делается увеличенная предупредительная пауза, а в случае тире пауза короче. (По правилу классическое двоеточие может заменяться тире.)

Answer (score 0):

Лиза, в зависимости от вкладываемого во фразу смысла могут быть варианты:

*Не важно, что это радио в такси или попавшая в почтовый ящик газета.*

*Не важно, что это: радио в такси или попавшая в почтовый ящик газета.*

Объяснение: пишущий должен ясно понимать, ЧТО ИМЕННО тут не важно))